# Program giving signal SIGABRT: Process abort signal in one code and does not in other code

Tags: arrays, ubuntu, error-handling, operating-system, gfortran

I am trying to run this code but I am not getting why I m receiving SEGMENTATION error for the code?

Apparently, when I am setting the value of y equal to 2.718(equal to e) the code is running fine without any error. But when I change the value of y, the code gives me the segmentation error.

> I tried the options of - fcheck for 'all' and 'bounds' both options but my device didnt return any error.
>   I am lot confused then, why the code is giving this error?? Please help me

```
program Trial
implicit none
 integer :: i,j,L,a,b,c,d,niter,time,mm,nn,N,k,g1,g2,w ! n is iteration time
 real :: r,h,E,Ei,Ef,f,E1,E2,S,y
 real :: JE=1.0
 integer, dimension(8) :: values
 integer, dimension(:,:), allocatable :: spin
 integer, dimension(:), allocatable :: seed
 !integer, dimension(0:100) :: G, Hi
 real, dimension(100) :: G,Hi,Hit, root
 !integer, dimension(0:1) :: 
 character(len=30) ::  charac_b
 !seed=44589
 charac_b = 'store_config'
 print *,'Enter the number of lattice points:'
 read *,L
 print *, 'Enter number of iterations:'
 read *,niter

!Initialisation of G & H. G is density of states and H is the Histogram
 do i=1,101
  G(i)=1.0
  Hi(i)=0.0
  Hit(i)=-200+4*(i-1)
 end do

f=2.71828183
do i=1,21
 root(i)=f
 f=f**(0.5)
end do
! Min fn gives minimum of the value
 allocate(spin(L,L))
 E=0.0
 S=0.0
 N=L*L

!Generator of Random Numbers 
 call date_and_time(VALUES=values)
 call random_seed(size=k)
 allocate(seed(k))
 seed(:)=values(:)
 call random_seed(put=seed)

!Initialising Data
 open(12,file="Data_initial.txt")
 do i=1,L
  do j=1,L
   call RANDOM_NUMBER(r)
   if(r<0.5) then
    spin(i,j)=+1
   else
    spin(i,j)=-1
   end if
  write(12,*) float(i),float(j),float(spin(i,j))
 end do
 end do
 close(12) 

!Calculating energies

 do i=1,L
  do j=1,L
   a=i+1;b=i-1;c=j+1;d=j-1
   if(i==L)a=1
   if(i==1)b=L
   if(j==1)d=L
   if(j==L)c=1

   !M=M+spin(i,j)
   E=E-JE*float((spin(i,j))*(spin(a,j)+spin(b,j)+spin(i,c)+spin(i,d)))
  end do
 end do
 E=E*0.5
 print *,'intial energy and per spin=',E,E/float(N)
 !print *,'initial magnetisation and per spin=',M,mag

!Going for a random flipping now
!f=2.71828183
!do kt=1,21
y=root(2)
!y=2.5
do time=1,niter
do mm=1,L
 do nn=1,L
  call RANDOM_NUMBER(r); i=int(r*float(L))+1
  call RANDOM_NUMBER(r); j=int(r*float(L))+1
  a=i+1;b=i-1;c=j+1;d=j-1
    if(i==L)a=1
    if(i==1)b=L
    if(j==1)d=L
    if(j==L)c=1
  Ei=-JE*float((spin(i,j))*(spin(a,j)+spin(b,j)+spin(i,c)+spin(i,d)))
  spin(i,j)=-spin(i,j)
  Ef=-JE*float((spin(i,j))*(spin(a,j)+spin(b,j)+spin(i,c)+spin(i,d)))
  E1=E
  E2=E1+(Ef-Ei)
  g1=int((E1+200.0)/4)+1
  g2=int((E2+200.0)/4)+1
  if(g2<=g1) then
   G(g2)=LOG(G(g2))+LOG(y)
   !G(g2)=G(g2)*f
   Hi(g2)=Hi(g2)+1
  else 
   call RANDOM_NUMBER(h)
   if(h<=G(g1)/G(g2)) then
    G(g2)=LOG(G(g2))+LOG(y)
    !G(g2)=G(g2)*f
    Hi(g2)=Hi(g2)+1
   else
    G(g1)=LOG(G(g1))+LOG(y)
    !G(g2)=G(g2)*f
    Hi(g1)=Hi(g1)+1
    spin(i,j)=-spin(i,j)
   end if
  end if
  E=E2
  end do
 end do
end do
 do i=1,101
   S=S+(Hit(i)*Hi(i))
 end do
 do i=1,101
  if(Hi(i) .lt. 0.95*(real(S/101.0))) then
   print *,"No",i
   exit
  end if
 end do
 do j=1,101
  Hi(j)=0.0
 end do
 !f=f**(0.5)
!end do
 open(13,file="Data_final.txt")
   do w=1,101
    write(13,*) Hit(w), G(w), Hi(w)
   end do
deallocate(spin)
deallocate(seed)
end program Trial
```

Comment: What is your initial data?

Comment: The initial data was a 10*10 array of values +1 &, - 1 representing spins. It was a random configuration.

Comment: Ok I think I have figured out the problem. Whats going on is that while looping eventually a negative number is being taken inside log owing to the algorithm whoch is resulting in NAN. So is this the reason why I m receiving segmentation error??

Comment: I don't know. Don't you have a backtrace? Use `gfortran -g -fbacktrace -Wall -fcheck=all`. We can't test yoir program without the input file...

Comment: The code generates a lattice of spins and is stored in spin array. Then the code tries to flip the sign by randomly taking a spin from the spin array. So firstly, the cide generates the array and use it as input.

Answer (score 1):

What you really have to do is to compile your program for error checking whenever you suspect a problem. I suggest to do it every time during development. Then, when asking here, you always have to report the complete program output, especially the complete error message. If you use the options I suggested in the comment

```
> gfortran -g -fbacktrace -Wall -fcheck=all spins.f90
```

and run the code, you have a lot of useful information

```
> ./a.out 
 Enter the number of lattice points:
5
 Enter number of iterations:
1
At line 22 of file spins.f90
Fortran runtime error: Index '101' of dimension 1 of array 'g' above upper bound of 100

Error termination. Backtrace:
#0  0x7f4df5a28640 in ???
#1  0x7f4df5a29185 in ???
#2  0x7f4df5a2952a in ???
#3  0x400fee in trial
        at spins.f90:22
#4  0x403f8c in main
        at spins.f90:141
```

which really should be included in your question.

It points to a specific line of code. Even without the checking option you still get the backtrace which still points to the line of code.

```
#3  0x400fee in trial
            at spins.f90:22
```

The output from the checking option is more specific.

```
Index '101' of dimension 1 of array 'g' above upper bound of 100
```

So the crash happens at the very begin

```
 do i=1,101
  G(i)=1.0
  Hi(i)=0.0
  Hit(i)=-200+4*(i-1)
 end do
```

because the arrays are only declared from 0 to 100, not 101.

The value of `y` appears to be a red herring. Unfortunately, several points in your question confused me and lead to examining wrong parts of the code. You probably did not apply `-=fcheck=all` option correctly or you only applied it to a different version of the code. Be sure to use it always and to re-run your code after using it.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for your help. Will take care next time.